# How do I Unit test is URL valid in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a class that checks to see if the URL is valid using the method below:

```
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) && 
        Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && 
        (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || 
        uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
```

I was wondering how I would unit test the code to check to see if the URL is valid or not.

So far, i have a unit test that only partially covers the unit test which is below.

```
string url = "newUrl";
var result = UrlUtility.IsValid(url);
Assert.IsFalse(result);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is. The method pretty much suggests all possible assertions. Just repeat what you've got and add fancier input like null-terminated string as a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cover all conditions of `IsValid()` method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestEmptyUrl()
{
    string url = "";

    Assert.IsFalse(UrlUtility.IsValid(url));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestInvalidUrl()
{
    string url = "bad url";

    Assert.IsFalse(UrlUtility.IsValid(url));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestRelativeUrl()
{
    string url = "/api/Test";

    Assert.IsFalse(UrlUtility.IsValid(url));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestUrlWithInvalidScheme()
{
    string url = "htt://localhost:4000/api/Test";

    Assert.IsFalse(UrlUtility.IsValid(url));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestUrlWithHttpScheme()
{
    string url = "http://localhost:4000/api/Test";

    Assert.IsTrue(UrlUtility.IsValid(url));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestUrlWithHttpsScheme()
{
    string url = "https://localhost:4000/api/Test";

    Assert.IsTrue(UrlUtility.IsValid(url));
}
```

Comment: How about a relative Url like `"../api/Test"`?

Comment: Thanks Roma and Filburt, it worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can give some values for the url. For example you can test the next case:

```
string url = string.Empty;
var result = UrlUtility.IsValid(url);
Assert.IsFalse(result);
```

Also, you can read about the **Uri.UriSchemeHttp** and **Uri.UriSchemeHttps** on the internet and try to make some test to respect or to ignore this uri scheme.
Hope it helps!